# Get an uploaded file from a html form in MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have this file upload input in part of a pretty large form:

```
<input class="input-file" type="file" name="picture">
```

I am using:

```
public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form)
```

To get the rest of my form values, and it comes up with 'picture' in the FormCollection as well, but it only has the filename and not the actual picture. I have tried using this:

```
public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFile picture)
```

And this

```
Request.Files[0]
```

which are solutions I found on other SO questions, but both remain null.

I assume the file is actually getting posted since it shows up in the FormCollection.

How can I get this file? Trying to get it as a byte[] to save in database.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: @VladCiobanu I'm using `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))` to start my form... How would I add multipart to this, if it's not done already? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have changed it to `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, enctype="multipart/form-data"}))` and have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the start of my form to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add","Recipe",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```